# How to scan a folder with AVG via the command line?

Tags: command-line, directory

I'm running avg anti virus on linux and I'm using only the terminal. So `sudo avgscan / -a -H -c` scans the whole disk, is there a way to scan just a specified folder (also scans for the folders within said folder)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch The AVG Anti-Virus on Ubuntu, run this command from the terminal:

`sudo avgctl --start`

Here are some useful scanning commands:

> To scan a specific folder, use this command by replacing "folder_name" with the folder you want to scan with AVG:

`sudo avgscan -H /folder_name`

> To download an update:

`sudo avgupdate -d`

> To update the current virus database, use one of these commands:

`sudo avgupdate --priority 1`
`sudo avgupdate --priority 2`
`sudo avgupdate --priority 3`
`sudo avgupdate --priority 4`
`sudo avgupdate --priority 5`

> 1 - Critical update
>
> 2 - Virus update
>
> 3 - Recommended update
>
> 4 - Program update (default)
>
> 5 - Optional update

To download an update:

`sudo avgupdate -d`

For more help about using AVG, run this command:

`sudo avgscan -h`

> Note: To stop the scan process, press Ctrl + C in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

> *is there a way to scan just a specified folder*

Yes, simply give it the folder path instead of the `/` you are using now.

For example:

```
sudo avgscan /home/shelby -a -H -c
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the full system scan was done using `/`, I was looking for some sort of specific command

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a terminal
2. To update AVG type `sudo avgupdate` - you then have to enter your password to get "sudo"-rights, then AVG will start updating
3. To scan your whole system type `sudo avgscan / -a -H -c --ignerrors` - this scans your system (`/`), all of the included (and maybe compressed) files (`a`), in a heuristic scan mode (`H`), your cookies (`c`), and ignores the normal I/O errors (= errors you get normally as linux protects system/proc - files.

Important: When doing `sudo avgscan / -a -H -c --ignerrors` you have to leave blank spaces between the commands so you type sudo then blank then avgscan then blank then / then blank then -a ...... and so on.

source: http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=218426

Comment: Does AVG still offer a (free) linux product? There's nothing "linux" listed under their ["All Products" page](http://www.avg.com/us-en/home-small-office-security#all-tab)